# Codefluent in memory tables

Tags: in-memory, codefluent

We are implementing in memory table technology in our application. There is one problem however: SQL server does not support rowversion (timestamp) in in memory tables. This is used by codefluent for concurrency protection.

Does anyone know a way to bypass this problem? We can't use the in memory tables at this point, which would be a big disappointment...

Comment: The optimistic concurrency is enabled by default, and can be disabled if needed ([blog post](https://blog.codefluententities.com/2010/01/13/concurrency-management-with-codefluent/)). If you do need concurrency and in memory tables, you'll need to implement a custom mechanism. Using an aspect you can change the code of the save and delete stored procedures.

Comment: Do you have any example of this or anyone else?

Comment: You'll find some aspects that change the code of the generated stored procedure on GitHub: [ReadOnSave](https://github.com/SoftFluent/CodeFluent-Entities/blob/master/Samples/SoftFluent.Samples.ReadOnSave.Aspects/SoftFluent.Samples.ReadOnSave.Aspects/ReadOnSaveAspect.cs), [SqlServerInMemoryAspect](https://github.com/SoftFluent/CodeFluent-Entities/blob/master/Extensions/SoftFluent.SqlServerInMemory/SoftFluent.SqlServerInMemory.Aspects/SoftFluent.SqlServerInMemoryAspect.cs)

Comment: [ExtendedSearchAspect](https://github.com/SoftFluent/CodeFluent-Entities/blob/master/Extensions/SoftFluent.ExtendedSearch/SoftFluent.Samples.ExtendedSearch.Aspects/ExtendedSearchAspect.cs), [EncryptAspect](https://github.com/SoftFluent/CodeFluent-Entities/blob/master/Extensions/SoftFluent.EncryptAspect/SoftFluent.Samples.EncryptAspect.Aspects/EncryptAspect.cs)